# Laravel 5.2 routes not working in production server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I configure Laravel 5.2.41 in server( Redhat7 with Apache&Mysql). The default welcome view is working but whenever I am trying to create a new route in routes.php page, the view of that newly created route is not working. But if I map the created route to welcome view its working. Please help me with good solution. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, read the help file [on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Thanks.

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled in the production server ? If not enable it.

Comment: mod_rewrite is on in production server